# Mockito mock with when returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I mock `articleElementSelector.getTag()` to return a string and use `InjectMocks` annotation to inject the mock into the constructor. In the debugger, I see that `articleElementSelector` is mocked (because of the CGLib stuff), but when `getTag()` is invoked, it returns null.

HomePageScraperTest:

```
public class HomePageScraperTest extends UnitTest {

    private static final String ARTICLE_TAG = "article";
    private static final String URL_HOME_ARTICLE_1 = "http://www.home1.com";
    private static final String URL_HOME_ARTICLE_2 = "http://www.home2.com";

    @InjectMocks
    private HomePageScraper homePageScraper;

    @Mock
    private JsoupParser jsoupParser;
    @Mock
    private ArticleScraper articleScraper;
    @Mock
    private ArticleElementSelector articleElementSelector;

    @Mock
    private Document homeDocument;
    @Mock
    private Element element1;
    @Mock
    private Element element2;
    @Mock
    private Elements elements1;
    @Mock
    private Elements elements2;

    private URL homeUrl;
    private Elements homeArticleElements = new Elements();
    private Article homeArticle1;
    private Article homeArticle2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        homeUrl = new URL(URL_HOME_ARTICLE_1);
        homeArticleElements.addAll(asList(element1, element2));
        homeArticle1 = anArticle().withTitle("article1").build();
        homeArticle2 = anArticle().withTitle("article2").build();
    }

    @Test
    public void scrape() {
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(homeUrl);
        when(articleElementSelector.getTag()).thenReturn(ARTICLE_TAG);
        when(jsoupParser.parse(homeUrl)).thenReturn(homeDocument);
        when(homeDocument.select(ARTICLE_TAG)).thenReturn(homeArticleElements);
        when(element1.select("a")).thenReturn(elements1);
        when(elements1.attr("href")).thenReturn(URL_HOME_ARTICLE_1);
        when(element2.select("a")).thenReturn(elements2);
        when(elements2.attr("href")).thenReturn(URL_HOME_ARTICLE_2);
        when(articleScraper.scrape(URL_HOME_ARTICLE_1)).thenReturn(homeArticle1);
        when(articleScraper.scrape(URL_HOME_ARTICLE_2)).thenReturn(homeArticle2);

        List<Article> articles = homePageScraper.scrape(homePage);

        assertThat(articles).containsOnly(homeArticle1, homeArticle2);
    }
}
```

HomePageScraper (only relevant code)

```
@Component
public class HomePageScraper extends AbstractPageScraper {

    private static final int HEADLINER_COUNT = 5;

    public HomePageScraper(JsoupParser parser, ArticleElementSelector articleElementSelector, ArticleScraper articleScraper) {
        super(parser, articleElementSelector, articleScraper);
    }
}
```

AbstractPageScraper

```
public abstract class AbstractPageScraper {

    private final String ARTICLE_TAG;

    private JsoupParser parser;

    ArticleScraper articleScraper;

    public AbstractPageScraper(JsoupParser parser, ArticleElementSelector articleElementSelector, ArticleScraper articleScraper) {
        this.parser = parser;
        ARTICLE_TAG = articleElementSelector.getTag(); // here the mock returns null
        this.articleScraper = articleScraper;
    }
}
```

The test worked before but after I refactored it, pulling up duplicate code in the abstract class, I bumped on this one.

Comment: I just replaced ARTICLE_TAG = articleElementSelector.getTag(); with         this.articleElementSelector = articleElementSelector; and the test is green af. Extra info why it previously didn't work is still wanted.

Comment: homePageScraper object was created before your when(articleElementSelector.getTag()).thenReturn(ARTICLE_TAG) inside scrape test method was executed. So it returned null. Either you can go with your update as per your above comment or you need to use initMocks inside your setup method in place of injects mock.